# TOC and figure side by side in a slide

Tags: latex

I want to put a figure and the TOC side by side in one slide where it would look like

TOC Figure

I have tried to include them each in a minipage respectively and then put them both in a figure environment.  But the result does not look good, for the TOC is formatted as a paragraph, instead of an itemize look.  So, does anybody have a better solution?  Thanks in advance.

PS

I use beamer for creating slides.

Comment: Which package or document class do you use to produce slides?

Comment: Thanks, Svante, I use beamer.

Comment: This is a valid question!  Please reopen.

Comment: Why put them into a figure environment?  Should not `\frame{\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}\ tableofcontents\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}\ includegraphics[...]{...}\end{minipage}}` suffice?

Comment: If you want a figure, replace or expand the `\includegraphics` part.

Comment: LaTeX questions appear to be on topic for Stackoverflow. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stackoverflow). Please vote to reopen. (And if you're going to close it anyway despite that, at least migrate the question to one of our sister sites.)

Comment: This sort of unilateral closing against community consensus seems contrary to the spirit of Stack Overflow. BTW, there is a proposal to create a StackOverflow-like site specifically for TeX/LaTeX (which may attract non-programmers, and also avoid closing by ignorant moderators as happened here): please go here and "commit": http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2148/tex-latex-and-friends?referrer=LtGW8MKLMIWU41zfK7oIpw2

Comment: Svante, thanks for typing. I tried the same thing before I post this question. The problem with minipage is that, TOC in it is formatted as regular paragraph. It does not look pretty good because lines of TOC entries gets too close.

And many thanks to Ken and ShreevatsaR for requesting reopen this question. I am new here and when I saw the question being closed I did not understand why. Because there have been thousands of latex questions asked here. Anyway, it is alive again.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the following:

```
\frame{
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \tableofcontents

    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}[h]
      \centering
      HERE-FIGURE
      \caption{Testfigure}
      \label{fig:a}
    \end{figure}

  \end{columns}
}
```

That worked just fine for me.